# Are there any bit.ly libraries for Android?

Tags: java, android, bit.ly, url-shortener

Are there any libraries that can do bit.ly URL shortening for Android/Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[bitlyj](http://code.google.com/p/bitlyj/): A Java interface to the bit.ly and j.mp APIs

note: google is your friend.

Comment: @SheehanAlam: Did you try "bit.ly URL shortening for Android/Java"? Cause that is what I used.